# Unrecognized VM option ' ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrentAndUnloadsClasses'

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

My Java project is failing to start with the error below.  This only started happening after I restarted my computer. What does this error mean?

```
Unrecognized VM option ' ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrentAndUnloadsClasses'
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Any insight into what might be causing this error would be appreciated.

***Details:** Java 5*

Comment: If you're really running Java 5, it looks like that option [only became available in Java 6u4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u4-140071.html) -- which would explain that error.  Is it possible you installed a newer Java, and put it on the `PATH` temporarily, and the restart wiped the `PATH` change?

Comment: @jedwards It looks like there was a script that changed my JAVA_HOME to point to Java 5 when my computer stats up. Setting my JAVA_HOME to Java 6 fixes the issue. Please put you comment in an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Great, happy to have helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really running Java 5, it looks like that option [only became available in Java 6u4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u4-140071.html) -- which would explain that error.

Is it possible you installed a newer Java, and put it on the PATH temporarily, and the restart wiped the PATH change?